# Can open api tools auto generate polymorphic rest client methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, polymorphism, openapi-generator

I have a little question, let me know if there is a better place to put the question:

i'm using "openapi" : "3.0.1" in a java spring boot project
and i'm try to auto generate a rest client base on this endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/new_test-endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<String> newTestEndpoint(@RequestBody
                                                  @Schema(oneOf = {FlatFileRequest.class, WebServiceRequest.class})
                                                  PayloadRequest payload);
```

PayloadRequest is an Interface and FlatFileRequest and WebServiceRequest its implementations.

Do you know guys if it is posible open api auto generate 2 diferente rest client methods for both PayloadRequest interface implementations ?

Now open api generate one rest client method and a DTO with all the properties that belongs to "FlatFileRequest" and "WebServiceRequest" classes.

in this way

```
public String newTestEndpoint(PayloadRequestDTO payload);
```

I would like open api to create two methods similar to:

```
public String newTestEndpoint(FlatFileRequestDTO payload);

public String newTestEndpoint(WebServiceRequestDTO payload);
```